# Why master is incrementing Address in AMBA AHB Burst transfer?

Tags: protocols, bus, amba

In AHB burst mode, master has to give only starting address and slave has to calculate the remaining address. But in the picture below (from AHB specification) address is incrementing at HAddress pin for every clock. Why? Am I wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The master has to change HADDR for every transfer in a burst, not just give the starting address.

The benefit of the master providing addresses is that the slave need not have  address incrementing logic inside it and can use the haddr signal on the bus. The benefit of a burst over a series of single transfers is simple: the slave can prepare for the next transfer while handling the current transfer since it "knows" the next address since addresses in a burst always increment by the same value. A series of single transfers *could* be a series of random addresses (the slave assumes the worst-case since it does not what is to appear on the bus) that might need be harder to handle by the slave.

Comment: If master is giving that then what is the advantage of having burst mode?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Haddress is not used by slave at every clock. The designers put those addresses for debbuging, and it's easier for slave to use the HBURST signal